# How to extract content from the quotation marks " MY TEXT " with PHP (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to extract some information out of a website.

My problem is that I need to extract text that is like this:

```
<p class="review"> "Desired text3" </p>
```

How to get the text that is inside the quotation marks **"** .... **"**?

Actually I've tried this but it wont work at all!

```
preg_match_all('|<p class=\"adress\">(.*)<\/p>|',$data,$text);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = '<p class="review"> "Desired text3" </p>';
preg_match_all('|>\s*"(.*)"\s*<\/|',$data,$text);
var_dump($text[1][0]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/uEaIU)